# Incorrectly stated corollary to fundamental theorem of algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question

Page 333 of Julie Miller and Donna Gerken's "College Algebra" 2nd edition:

---

Linear Factorization Theorem:

If $f(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + .... + a_1x + a_0$ where $n \geq 1$, then:

$f(x) = a_n(x-c_1)(x-c_2)...(x-c_n)$, where $c_1,...,c_n$ are complex numbers.

*Note: The complex number $c_1,...,c_n$ are not necessarily unique*

---

It's the note that I'm having issue with. Wouldn't these be the $n$ roots of $f(x)$ and thus be unique? Perhaps the authors meant to say distinct...?

Comment: sure, distinct if you like that better (I do, but I've also seen some write unique).

Comment: "Distinct" is meant; "unique" is incorrect in that, at best, it invites confusion.